# Open folder only knowing the name partially

Tags: cmd, visual-foxpro

I have a bunch of folders named like "XXXXX John Doe". I know the X part, not the name afterwards, however, the X part is always unique. Manually i could just TAB, however i don't know how to do it via cmd only.

I used to be able to just do this:

```html
"! \n explorer.exe "  + rootdirectory + foldername
```

Now, since the folder structure naming scheme changed, im struggling finding a way to open folders,  regardless of it having a (name) suffix or not.

This question is for Microsoft's cmd and it's gonna be called by a VisualFoxPro program.

Comment: In a Windows command prompt window can be used: `@for /D %I in ("C:\Path to\Parent Folder\XXXXX *") do @%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,"%I"`. Both `%I` must be `%%I` on using this command line in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

You could ADIR() in VFP to get the actual name of the file and then use that in the call to Explorer. Presumably you know the name of the folder that contains the folder you're looking for, so something like this:

```
LOCAL aFolder[1], nFolders, nFolder
CD <the parent folder>

nFolders = ADIR(aFolder, '','D') && gives you all folders in the parent folder

IF nFolders = 1
   nFolder = 1
ELSE
   nFolder = ASCAN(aFolder, 'XXXXX', -1, -1, 1, 13)
ENDIF

* Now do your call to Explorer, passing aFolder[m.nFolder] as the folder name
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest command is using ForFiles but do consider safety improvements below

```
forfiles /m XXXXX* /C "cmd /c explorer /e,@path"
```

OR slightly longer but more likely to only run with `cd` & folder *thus not launch a similar filename** by mistake.

```
forfiles /m XXXXX* /C "cmd /c cd /d @path&explorer ."
```

This works on the basis that you are searching from the root folder and not somewhere a random explorer bat or otherwise gotcha is lurking.

first as @mofi suggests ensure explorer is well defined so replace that as `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe`

/m is based on the premise it is a foldername rather than any filename that is found thus must be run in the sub folders root and you can enforce that by adding `/p "rootdirectory"` before  /m

As constructed it works best if folders are exactly as specified i.e. a fixed unique ID followed by a space and then variable naming.

**finally** a shorter method but beware the need for escapes and also be aware that without the `cd` restriction it can launch any random files such as xxxxxx.txt thus I consider the "cd" method above as safest for calling a folder.

`forfiles /p "rootfolder" /m XXXXX* /C "cmd /c start \"\" @path"`

Comment: It does not make sense to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe` not existing at all on Windows XP and older Windows versions which searches for files __and__ folders matching the wildcard pattern in comparison to using `for /D`. Further it does not make sense to let `forfiles` execute `cmd.exe` just to execute `explorer.exe`. There could be also executed `explorer.exe` by `forfiles` directly using `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /M XXXXX* /C "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,@path"` which starts only one `explorer.exe` although specified twice on command line.